# Word for a completely new idea in a particular field

Tags: single-word-requests

A new way to think of something, which is a gamechanger.

For instance:

> - Video on demand is killing the digital establishment. What can we call the VOD market?

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. *Per* the checklist in the [SWR tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info): *How will you choose the best word? What is "best"?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first phrase that came to mind for me was [**disruptive technology**](https://www.americanfunds.com/individual/insights/investment-insights/2017-disruptive-technology.html?cid=ps_ggl_802212614&s_kwcid=AL!5214!3!173225609960!e!!g!!disruptive%20technology&ef_id=Wkj3GwAAASajhm-q:20180818050213:s) or [**disruptive innovation**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/disruptive_innovation).

Here is the definition I found on Wikipedia:

> In business, a disruptive innovation is an innovation that creates a new market and value network and eventually disrupts an existing market and value network, displacing established market-leading firms, products, and alliances.

Source - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptive_innovation

Here are some [examples](https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/digital-mckinsey/our-insights/disruptive-technologies) of disruptive technologies from the recent past:

- [Mobile   Internet](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/arts-and-entertainment/wp/2014/03/12/36-ways-the-web-has-changed-us/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.8b8dea714efd)
- [Cloud    Computing](https://www.ringcentral.com/blog/2017/05/6-ways-cloud-computing-is-changing-the-business-world/)
- [3D Printing](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ways-3d-printing-change-world/)
- [Advanced Robotics](https://www.engadget.com/2017/02/07/how-robotics-is-changing-the-world-around-us/)

Comment: We're looking for answers from experts in the field. “[You have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text … is not your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077 "“Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?” – SE Meta")”.

Comment: As a notional "expert in the field" (I have worked in multiple companies developing disruptive technologies - with varying degrees of success) I approve this answer; it is pretty much what I would have written.

Answer (score 1):

How about **novel**?

:[Merriam-Webster's]
*not known or experienced before*

"That's a novel idea for a TV series!"

Synonyms of novel
*fresh, new, original, strange, unaccustomed, unfamiliar, unheard-of, unknown, unprecedented*

Words Related to novel: 
*innovative, unique*

Answer (score 0):

[**Revolutionary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary)

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 c** : constituting or bringing about a major or fundamental change • a *revolutionary* new product

Comment: Same comment as before: We're looking for answers from experts in the field.  “[You have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text … is not your work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077 "“Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?” – SE Meta")”.

Comment: This is a pretty typical single-word request. You don't get experts, you get opinions, and you get accused of something.